# Unable to see any columns in table after running AWS Glue crawler

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am relatively new to AWS Glue, but after creating my crawler and running it successfully, I can see that a new table has been created but I can't see any columns in that table. It is absolutely blank.

I am using a .csv file from a S3 bucket as my data source.

[image]

Comment: Can you post few sample records here?

Answer (score 0):

1. Is your file UTF8 encoded... Glue has a problem if it’s not.
2. Does your file have at least 2 records
3. Does the file have more than one column.

There are various factors that impact the crawler from identifying a csv file

Please refer to this documentation that talks about the built in  classifier and what it needs to crawl a csv file properly

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-classifier.html